# Do you lose concealment when you attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, concealment

In D&D4E if you have concealment and make an attack, are you still concealed?

As a specific example, a Warlock gains concealment from his Shadow Walk power, then wishes to make a ranged attack.  Does he lose the concealment bonus after making the attack?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.**

Nothing in the rules for Concealment<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=glossary&id=169)</sup> says anything about losing the benefit when making an attack.

I think you're confusing it with the rules for the Stealth<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/skill.aspx?id=20)</sup> skill, which explicitly mentions that you stop being hidden when you make an attack.

As for your specific example: yes, the warlock would stay concealed until EONT. Nothing in the description of the Warlock<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=7)</sup> class puts any restrictions on the Concealment gained from *Shadow Walk*, which in turn means that the standard rules for the condition apply.